# Android 13- Unable to connect with WiFi netork after few attempts

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-connectivitymanager, android-13

User is unable to connect with Wi-Fi network initially, but after few attempts we are getting **"No devices found. Make sure devices are turned on and available to connect."**

```
WifiNetworkSpecifier wifiNetworkSpecifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                    .setSsid(<SSID>)
                    .setWpa2Passphrase(<Password>)
                    .setIsHiddenSsid(true)
                    .build();

NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                    .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                    .setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier)
                    .build();

connectivityManager.requestNetwork(networkRequest, networkCallbacks);
```

We are seeing this issue only on **Google Pixel 4(Android 13)** device.

Same code is working fine **Pixel Android [version 10, 11 12] device**.

Comment: Similar issues here on a Pixel 6a with Android 13, and even when not using a hidden SSID. It’s _incredibly_ annoying really. Sometimes it does work, sometimes it doesn’t. And it’s entirely unclear when and why it does or does not work.

Comment: exactly @PattaFeuFeu I created a issue in google tracker, got the reply as they are going to fix on future build.

Google issue tracker link here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/271014975